# is nested Linq faster than foreach loop?

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Is this "better", faster or easier to read:

```
 var viewsOnSheet = templateSheet.GetAllViewports()
    .Select(x => doc.GetElement(x))
    .Cast<Viewport>()
    .Select(x => doc.GetElement(x.ViewId))
    .Cast<View>();
```

...than this:

```
foreach (ElementId id in templateSheet.GetAllViewports())
{
    Viewport vp = doc.GetElement(id) as Viewport;
    View v = doc.GetElement(vp.ViewId) as View;
}
```

They both work, I am just curious if there is some programming standard that I would be violating with so many nested Linq calls. What's easier to understand? I am personally leaning towards the `foreach` loop.

Thanks!

Comment: Well I wouldn't use `as` in this case anyway - if the type is wrong, would you rather have a descriptive `InvalidCastException`, or a `NullReferenceException` that doesn't tell you whether the element was actually null or a non-null reference to the wrong type? I'd probably use LINQ but put the cast directly into the `Select` call instead of calling `Cast`.

Comment: so instead of `.Select(x => doc.GetElement(x))` you would say go with `.Select(x => (Viewport)doc.GetElement(x))` ?

Comment: Yes, I would. But this is really an opinion-based question.

Comment: That's fine. I am looking for an opinion of someone who's got more experience than me, so that I can learn decent habits. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: No, it's not fine - because opinion-based questions are discouraged on SO.

Comment: Are you saying that people are coming to downvote and i should delete this questions before anyone gets an idea to actually post an answer?

Comment: I'm saying that you shouldn't have posted it, and you should delete the question and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. I would not describe people downvoting inappropriate questions as trolls.

Comment: If you want to know if code X is faster than code Y then you race X against Y and find out. This question is like showing me two pictures of horses and asking me which one is faster. Much better that I race the horses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Linq-to-objects, code with `foreach` is always marginally faster that equivalent LINQ call just because at the end LINQ end up with similar `foreach` after several method calls. For Linq-to-SQL/Linq-to-XML equivalent code with less function calls would be faster too just because you execute less code.

Note that proper matching code for more complex LINQ expressions may not be easy to write (try writing `GroupBy` yourself correctly) and definitely will not be shorter than LINQ.

Whether this performance different matters for your application - measure yourself against your particular performance goals.

Style of code is strictly personal preference - pick whatever works for you/your team.

Comment: Thank you sir for a clear and concise answer. I will make sure in the future to read up a little more before posting.

Comment: I'm not sure you can strictly say, "is always marginally faster".